# Resource field error - AWS S3 access point

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to access my s3 bucket from some specify IP address that would visit my s3 bucket with S3 restful api.

But I can't set-up the access point policy successful.

aws show me some error in my policy json.

following is my policy json:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id":<Id>,
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "IPAllow",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                  "s3:*"
             ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>"
                ],
            "Condition": {
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": [
                        "<my ip>"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I pretty sure my bucket arn is correct, but aws show following error:
`Unsupported Resource ARN In Policy: The resource ARN is not supported for the resource-based policy attached to resource type S3 Access Point.`

I had try to change action value or remove one of resource array, but it's still not work.

Comment: Can you remove `"arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>"` and try?

Comment: I tried but still doesn't work

Comment: "When you specify users in a Principal element, you cannot use a wildcard (*) to mean "all users". Principals must always name specific users." Remove the principal.

Comment: I can't remove principle, if remove that would get error : "Missing principal" , In the aws document
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_principal.html
I think "Principal : "*"" is correct.

Comment: Yes, totally my bad. You are right. I tested youir policy in my bucket and I do not see any errors. Are you attaching this policy to s3 right?

Comment: I added it in s3 - access point.
My situation is to expose the bucket and let specific ips do restful operations

Comment: Noo what a mess. You need to give arn of your access point, not that of the bucket. I totally missed the access point 'point'! Note that you need to have a similar access on the bucket as well. If the bucket policy denies such action, it will be denied.

Comment: oh... I didn't understand access point meaning before. sorry
Thank you for your patience